# Error in Listing my YouTube playlists

Tags: swift, youtube-api, alamofire

I got my user access token via Google signin iOS sdk.
Then I use the following source code to get my playlists in YouTube:

```
func listMyPlaylists(completionHandler: @escaping (_ result: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> ())
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists")!
    let parameters: Parameters = ["part": "id","mine": "true"]
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, "Content-Type": "application/json"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { json in

        if let error = json.result.error
        {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
        else
        {
            completionHandler(json.result.value, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got the following error. What do I miss?

```
{
error =     {
    code = 403;
    errors =         (
                    {
            domain = global;
            message = "Insufficient Permission";
            reason = insufficientPermissions;
        }
    );
    message = "Insufficient Permission";
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you didn't include the scope of your authorization as stated in [Youtube API Common request errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.api.CommonRequestError)

> forbidden (403) - insufficientPermissions The OAuth 2.0 token provided
>   for the request specifies scopes that are insufficient for accessing
>   the requested data.

One of the [Youtube scopes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#Obtaining_Access_Tokens) you can use is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @noogui answer and here I want to explain how you can achieve this
- Check your scope you set and if it is **kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeReadonly**  then change it to **kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeUpload**

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeUpload]
```

And set this in to the **viewDidLoad**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
```

Here is the list of scopes you can check

> kGTLRAuthScopeYouTube
>   kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeForceSsl
>   kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeUpload
>   kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeReadonly
>   kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeYoutubepartner
>   kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeYoutubepartnerChannelAudit